# How to Image resize this container in product page - Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, product-images, catalog, image, product-page

In the product page i need to resize the product image container but i can't how to resize this, Please check the image for reference

The below image shown with big gap between the image and border

[image]

**The result i need**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**you need to reduce the left image section width, please review below image**

[image]